# Reshaping my data to introduce a secondary axis (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to reshape my data, but I don't know how to do that. Let's use simple data:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(21.810, 22.086, 21.972, 22.214, 21.871, 22.352)
c <- c(411.6443, 412.8378, 411.9041, 413.6155, 402.0946, 411.6599)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

So when I try the following code the result is not what I want (I want the right axis to has the `c` vector range and the left axis the `b` vector range).

```
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=df$a, y=df$b))+geom_line(aes(x=df$a , y=df$b))+geom_point(aes(x=df$a, y=df$c))+geom_line(aes(x=df$a , y=df$c))+scale_y_continuous(name = "First Axis",sec.axis = sec_axis( ~.*410.626/22, name="Second Axis"))
```

EDIT. This is an example of what type of graphic I want

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: 1) don't use $ in aes 2)  don't use a second y axis https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/ - and this blog also suggests options, including the connected scatter plot which is a great way to show association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update II due to concerns of tjebo** please see comments:
More proper way:

1. Make transformation in df
2. bring into long format
3. remove `y` `aes` from `geom_line()`

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(c_transformed = c/(410.626/22)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(b, c_transformed),
    names_to = 'names',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) %>% 
  arrange(names) 

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = a, y = value, color = names)) + 
  geom_line() +   
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*(410.626/22), name = "second y")) +
  theme_classic()
p
```

[image]

**Update:** Op edit of question:

Something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = b, color = "b")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = c/(410.626/22), color = "c")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*(410.626/22), name = "second y")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**First answer:**
Please consider the comments by tjebo. But here is a solution how you can do it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = b)) +
  geom_point(aes(y =b)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = c/10)) +
  geom_point(aes(y =c/10))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "second y"))
```

[image]

data:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(21.810, 22.086, 21.972, 22.214, 21.871, 22.352)
c <- c(411.6443, 412.8378, 411.9041, 413.6155, 402.0946, 411.6599)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Comment: I just edited the post. Do you know if the aesthetics could be like the image that I have added? My teacher asked me to do this type of plot and I need to do it for a research (although it is not recommended). Thanks!

Comment: you sure `geom_point(y = ...)` is working? Haven't tried it, but I feel there is a call to `aes` missing

Comment: Even if it works (which I now tested and indeed, it works, which really surprised me) - I'd hardly recommend not to put y into the aes call. I'd recommend to be very explicit that you're setting the aesthetics, in order not to confuse yourself and/or others, and maybe generate peculiar and unexpected side effects.

Comment: Ok, the evaluation of b happens miraculously in the environment of the data frame passed to ggplot(). But it is the vector in the given order and doesn't work as an aesthetic. I am reassured - also clearly this only works by chance in your example.  consider `a <- 1:3;
b <- 1:3;
df <- data.frame(a = as.character(a),b);
ggplot(df, aes(x = forcats::fct_reorder(a, b, .desc = T))) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = b)) +
  geom_line(y = b, aes(group = 1))`

Comment: Thank you very much tjebo for this important notice. I have edited again my answer. Please tell me if this is what you mean.

Comment: Yeah - that's better because you're passing y into the global aesthetic. The problem is in the second option. Let me do the edit, and you'll see what I mean